# python subprocess use

Tags: python, subprocess, secure-crt

Sorry if this question has been asked 100 times before, unfortunately, i haven't found it if it was.  I am looking to write a python script which will spawn a background process and monitor it to see if it has completed.  I have seen the os.system command which is now recommended to utilize subprocess.call, but this seems to block the program until the process completes.

My end goal is to have the following:

1) Program runs and starts processessing sing information

2) Halfway through the program it will start a Windows DOS program which will need to run simultaneously

3) Program continues to run and keeps processing data.

4) Program monitors the DOS program and when it exits and then sends final information.  But the DOS program must have exited for it to run this step.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

---

More info: I am trying to utilize the python processor built into Securecrt.  It appears to open the CMD window fine for the program, but it does not print out any of the middle commands (just enable's in this example) until i kill the subprocess.

```
import os

import subprocess


def Main()

    crt.Screen.Synchronous = True

    VMCOMMAND = '\"C:\\Program Files\\VMWare\\VMware OVF Tool\\ovftool.exe\" ' + '--name=test' + ' C:\\temp\\test.ova' + ' vi://root:test@1.1.1.1'

    from subprocess import Popen


    p = Popen(VMCOMMAND)

    crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
    crt.Screen.Send("enable" + chr(13))
    crt.Screen.Send("enable" + chr(13))
    crt.Screen.Send("enable" + chr(13))
    crt.Screen.Send("enable" + chr(13))


    returncode = p.wait()

    crt.Screen.Send("should not see enable" + chr(13))

Main ()
```

Comment: "a Windows DOS program"? Programs are either for DOS or for Windows, there is no such thing as a "Windows DOS program".

Comment: Sorry Ignacio, this is a Windows DoS program running on Windows 7.  The program is basically the cmd line for ovftool.

Comment: OVFTool isn't for DoS, it's for virtualization.

Comment: ovftool has a dos cmdline interface that you can utilize to install a OVA/OVF file to a VM.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's a Windows program.

Comment: ok..thanks Ignacio.  I must have a really cool version, but i am able to run it from a DOS shell.

Comment: Windows doesn't have DOS shells anymore.

Comment: ok..i am utilizing the Windows command Line interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#popen-constructor) constructor:

```
from subprocess import Popen

# start program
p = Popen(["program.exe", "arg1"])
# do other stuff here
# ...
# at the end wait for the program to exit
returncode = p.wait()
# run final step here
```

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that and it didn't work.  I updated my original item with more info.  I failed to mention that I am trying to utilize the SecureCRT Python interpreter.

Comment: @ozymandius100: Does it work if you start some other program e.g., `notepad.exe`? Are you trying to send `'enable\r'` to `ovftool.exe`?

Comment: Interesting ....i did this just by launching "notepad.exe", and that did work without incident.  When i run ovatool.exe it doesn't(although ovatool keeps a cmd window open).....as for the enable...thats just txt output i am sending to the Securecrt.  process.  It looks like i needed the shell=False flag to get that working correctly.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a process has terminated without actually blocking you can use [`subprocess.Popen.poll`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).